# Is there a way to configure memory and time limits to visual studio code just like leetcode IDE?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

sometimes doing all the code right by self and when posting on online compilers it shows TLE or MLE . Is there a way so that i can limit the resource to visual studio so that it imitates like leetcode or hackkerank IDE...

couldnt find any solution publicly available to google search

Comment: Those websites usually embed the posted solution within code that allows to measure time and memory consumption, and decide for passed/non passed tests.

Comment: You can write your own timers / memory usage checks. If it goes beyond, then just make it fail.

Comment: Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code are two completely different software tools. Which one do you actually mean?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'll clear up something really quick*: Visual Studio Code is not an IDE, it's a text editor. Therefore it's not up to  it to decide the compilation and linking process. It can however integrate into shell to run shell commands to build your project.

On Linux you can use the `time` utility to verify that your running time is reasonable. You can run it from a terminal like that.

```
$ time path/to/my_program.exe
```

As for windows, I don't know any good built-in alternatives, except that I know that in PowerShell there's a `Measure-Command` cmdlet. If your VSCode terminal shell is PowerShell you can type the following:

```
> Measure-Command { path/to/my_program.exe }
```

To check memory usage of your program I can recommend using `valgrind`. This tool is useful for detecting many kinds of memory issues. You can learn more about it [here](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html).

To make this easier you can integrate these commands into your **build tasks**. You can learn more about those [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Note that these tools will simply display information about the usage of time and memory in your program, they won't error-out on large limits. So you'll have to manually check the output of these commands if you want to verify your program's efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `std::chrono` to implement time based limits at runtime.

Or at least emit a "pass"/"fail" condition at runtime depending on whether the limit was exceeded or not.